# Create a conditional formating macro for text value on Excel

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Very often I need to create conditional formating rules on my excel worksheets, not always on the same range, to format the text color depending on what's written.

The most common situation is turning all the cells in the range that have the text "Effective" green and bold, and "Not effective" red and bold.

I tried to create this macro using the Record Macro function on the Developer tab, but it didn't work, the code was blank.

As I have zero knowledge on VBA, I was wondering if somebody could give me a help creating this macro.

Definitions:

- There's no fixed range, it needs to capture the selected range;
- Format based on text, if "Effective" green and bold, if "Not effective" red and bold.
- Only for one sheet.

[Solved]

```
Sub EffectiveNot()
'
' EffectiveNot Macro
'
    Dim rStart As Range
    Set rStart = Selection
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Effective", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -11489280
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Not effective", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you checked your `ThisWorkbook`-Module? The macro recorder adds a new empty module each day you run it, then dumps the code in there...

This is basically what the macro recorder comes up with, after I cleaned it up a bit. Feel free to swap `Selection` to a range-object more appropriate for your use.

```
Option Explicit

Sub format()

    With Selection
        With .FormatConditions
            .Delete

            With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""Not Effective""")
                With .Font
                    .Color = vbRed
                    .Bold = True
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With

            With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""Effective""")
                With .Font
                    .Color = vbGreen
                    .Bold = True
                End With
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```